# Best Practise write CSS with SCSS for website responsive

Tags: css, sass

When I want to create a responsive website, say there are two devices with different screen. 
What should I create @media screen {} for different file, like code below:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 676px) {//Some code here}
```

or write @media screen {} directly for same file?. This example my code:

```
.home { 
   .container { 
      padding: 10px 0 20px 0; 
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
          padding: 2px 0 10px 0 
        } 
   }
}
```

And please include examples as my reference material.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the below approaches:

1. Use one media query for all elements that will be added it the
   bottom of your `scss` file.
2. Add each media query with it's element, like you did. I don't prefer
   that approach because it will make it harder to find/edit your code
   when working on large projects.

Example 1

```
.section--about {
  text-align: center;

  p {
    color: #727272;
  }
}

@include mobile {
  .section--about {
    p {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }
}
```

Exmple 2

```
.section--about {
  text-align: center;

  p {
    color: #727272;
  }

  @include mobile {
    p {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }
}
```

Further reading:

- [Approaches to Media Queries in Sass](https://css-tricks.com/approaches-media-queries-sass/)
- [Sass Guidelines](http://sass-guidelin.es/#responsive-web-design-and-breakpoints)
- [Write Better Media Queries with Sass](https://davidwalsh.name/write-media-queries-sass)
- [Media Queries mixins for Sass](https://github.com/paranoida/sass-mediaqueries)